# Practical usage of "shift" shell builtin command?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I checked the `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id`(part of `openssh-client` package at least under Debian) shell-script and it contains following if-statement:

```
if [ "-i" = "$1" ]; then
  shift
  # check if we have 2 parameters left, if so the first is the new ID file
  if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    if expr "$1" : ".*\.pub" > /dev/null ; then
      ID_FILE="$1"
    else
      ID_FILE="$1.pub"
    fi
    shift         # and this should leave $1 as the target name
  fi
else
```

What is the point of `shift` commands? I mean I know that `shift n` shell builtin shifts `n` number of arguments from left to right, but what is the reason to use it in this script? Why not use:

```
if [ "-i" = "$1" ]; then
  if [ -n "$3" ]; then
    if expr "$2" : ".*\.pub" > /dev/null ; then
      ID_FILE="$2"
    else
      ID_FILE="$2.pub"
    fi
  fi
```

Comment: I'm assuming these arguments are actually going somewhere else at some point, right? And anyway, you and the script author both could benefit from a `case` statement here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you do after you've parsed the `-i` option? There are more arguments to parse. If `-i` was the first argument, then after processing it, you need to look at the third argument. In the old version of `ssh-copy-id` you're looking at, `-i` is the sole option and the argument after that is the target host name. If `-i` is not passed, the target host name is the first argument.

```
if [ "$1" = "-i" ]; then
  …
  target_host_name=$3
else
  target_host_name=$1
fi
```

This doesn't scale when there are multiple options. You'd need to keep track of the current position in the argument list.

```
if [ "${$position}" = "-i" ]; then
  …
  position=$((position+2))
fi
target_host_name=${$position}
```

The thing is, what I wrote here is not valid shell syntax. There's no easy construct to get the nth argument; you can do it with `eval`, but it's awkward, and antique shells couldn't deal with multi-digit argument numbers.

So instead, each time an option is processed, it's removed from the list, by calling `shift`. If the option has an argument, call `shift 2`, or call `shift` a second time to remove the option argument. Then after processing each option, the next argument to process is always `$1`. It's simpler that way.

```
if [ "$1" = "-i" ]; then
  …
  shift 2
fi
…
target_host_name=$1
```